# web client request caching issue in wp7 app

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7

i'd created a `json web service` & used in my web site.
    Now i want use it in my windows phone app to show the data, which is receiving by that web service. So that i'v written the code below--->

```
//// some code

StartThread();
        }

            void StartThread()
            {
                DispatcherTimer TradeThread = new DispatcherTimer();
                TradeThread.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                TradeThread.Tick += new EventHandler(BindData);
                TradeThread.Start();
            }

            void BindData(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("some URL"));
                wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
            }

            void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
                ///// some code
```

The code is working fine, **But after some requests the data is not updating. So i think there is some caching problem** & i dont know **how to disable caching or any alternative way to get updated data on each requets** bcoz i'v never used web client befor.

So if anyone have used the web services than plz check my code above & do comment or edit it if have any solution for this caching problem ...........thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy workaround is to append a value that changes on earch request at the end of the query string:

```
"?disablecache=" + Environment.TickCount
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a no-cache header to the request:

```
wc.Headers.Add("Cache-Control: no-cache");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the "Cache-Control" header this way:

```
wc.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
```

Comment: :still not working (data is not updating) any other way to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried Oliver's trick and it worked!

I'm having some trouble using the extra parameter in my method which caters for requests with and without parameters.

So I tried this and it worked:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();    
wc.Headers["If-Modified-Since"] = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString();
```